# Schedule an API call in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, typescript, jenkins

I have a react based web app which retrieves data from Jenkins APIs. During the componentDidMount() function I'm calling the first API which starts the API calling flow. Then I will render the component with the data from the API.

The Jenkins server starts building each project at 7.00am every day. Therefore I want to call these APIs from React around 8.00pm everyday.

Can we schedule React to call these APIs and get it's updated data as previously mentioned during a specific time of the day? Or refresh browser etc which results in new API data? I'm new  to React so appreciate your suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: Simply use `setTimeout` within your component.

Comment: I guess a better suggestion would be [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), which would allow you to retrieve the data on a set interval rather than just once

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru Perhaps `setTimeout()` for the timespan until 8pm, then `setInterval()` for 24h ;)

Comment: @channae, Did the solution below work for you? If so, please consider marking my answer as "accepted" and/or by giving it an up-vote to show that it was useful. Thanks

Comment: @Chris I tried this unfortunately this didn't work. I tried putting a console.log and it didn't trigger. Also there were no logs in the browser's developer console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You correctly use your API calls within `componentDidMount()`. You can use `setTimeout()` on mount to wait until 20:00 and and trigger that event again with `setInterval()` every 24 hours after that.

So like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();  //current unix timestamp
  const execTime = new Date().setHours(20,0,0,0);  //API call time = today at 20:00
  let timeLeft;
  if(currentTime < execTime) {
    //it's currently earlier than 20:00
    timeLeft = execTime - currTime;
  } else {
    //it's currently later than 20:00, schedule for tomorrow at 20:00
    timeLeft = execTime + 86400000 - currentTime
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {

      //your code

    }, 86400000);  //repeat every 24h
  }, timeLeft);  //wait until 20:00 as calculated above
}
```

In other words, it will:

1. Calculate the time difference between now and next `20:00` o'clock.
2. Wait until `20:00` with `setTimeout()`.
3. Set a trigger for exactly 24 hours (*i.e 86400000 ms*) to repeat the code inside `setInterval()`.

This will work no matter when you start your React app.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately this didn't work. I tried putting a console.log and it didn't trigger. Also there were no logs in the browser's developer console.

Comment: @channae weird because it worked for me. Can you test it again? For the testing, set the trigger time to 1 minute in the future (replace `20,0,0,0` with your local time + 1 minute) and then also replace `86400000` with `1000` to test it. Also perhaps just replace your API call with a console log or similar.

Comment: I tried as you suggested by replacing 86400000 with 1000. I can see it triggers each second. But it doesn't wait for the future time it just triggers every second as soon as start the project.

Comment: I'm checking the time during //your code block and time is as follows,
current time 1516343495845 
exec time 1516344000000
I have put the exe time to 12.10 where time is around 12.03 right now

Comment: I changed it to timeLeft =  execTime - currentTime; apparently time left was in minus. Please accept my edit I'll accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: @channae ah of course. Thanks! The else part is correct though. What a blunder heheh